# .py script for automating a function

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm looking for a way to do the following:

- import attachment from email client, for example Gmail
- save this file XXX.xlsx -> convert this to CSV but in the name format have the date YYYYMMDD.csv
- Then finally this needs to be uploaded to a specific SFTP folder.

And this on a daily basis.

What I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file_from_email.xlsx')
df.to_csv('2020.csv') 


## covert file to correct date

import os
import datetime

Current_Date = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%m%d')
os.rename(r'C:\temp\conversion\2020.csv',r'C:\temp\conversion\2020' + str(Current_Date) +'.csv')
```

How do i convert it to csv and change the name of the file in one action to the current date time in YYYYMMDD.csv format? Thx in advance

Comment: what do you by "select the file with the ('current date'.csv)" ?
Note that you can save it with the desired file name when saving it with pandas

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question,

For what I understand you want "to select" a file, IMO that means reference it by a variable but I may be wrong if so I encourage you to edit your question.
There are a lot of hardcoded things in your code, and you may encounter other bugs with path...

```
out_file=os.path.join(r'C:\temp\conversion\2020', str(Current_Date) +'.csv')
# this variable out_file is the path to file your want.
# if you rename
os.rename(r'C:\temp\conversion\2020.csv', out_file)

# you can now access the file by its path using out_file. if it exists
```

EDIT: I am not sure of what your asked for. From what I understand your question is about how to make the name of the file in the format you chose.

```
#replace your Current date in your code by that:
Current_Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
print(Current_Date)
```

Comment: Hi RomainL., Ok let me rephrase it.

I need to have the csv name as following - YYYYMMDD.csv when it is send to the ftp.

The original file coming in email attach does not have this name yet. And it therefor when i convert from xlsx to csv, id like to save it to the 'current_data' in that format.

Comment: Im afraid not, my code already puts the correct name but its now in 2 steps. While i was hoping to rename it directly after converting to cvs with pandas.

Comment: I don't understand your probelm sorry